# Переделать аллокатор под бинарное дерево

Tags: c++, ооп, бинарное-дерево, контейнеры

Есть абразец аллокатора
TALLOCATOR.H

```
#ifndef TALLOCATOR_H
#define TALLOCATOR_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdexcept>

struct TNTree {
    TNTree* sons;
    void* data;
    size_t N;
};

class TAllocator
{
private:
    size_t free;
    size_t amount;
    size_t sizeOfBlock;

    TNTree* root;
    char* usedBlocks;
public:
    TAllocator(const size_t&, const size_t&);
    void* allocate();
    void deallocate(void*);
    ~TAllocator();
};

#endif
```

TALLOCATOR.CPP

```
#include "TAllocator.h"

TAllocator::TAllocator(const size_t& size, const size_t& amountToAdd)
{
    sizeOfBlock = size;
    amount = amountToAdd;
    root->N = amount;
    root->sons = (TNTree*)malloc(sizeof(TNTree) * root->N);
    usedBlocks = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * sizeOfBlock * amount);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        root->sons[i].data = malloc(sizeOfBlock);
        root->sons[i].data = usedBlocks + i * sizeOfBlock;
    }

    free = amountToAdd;
}

void* TAllocator::allocate()
{
    void* result = nullptr;

    if (free > 0) {
        result = root->sons[free - 1].data;
        free--;
    } else {
        throw std::runtime_error("TAllocator: out of memory");
    }
}

void TAllocator::deallocate(void* ptr)
{
    root->sons[free].data = ptr;
    free++;
}

TAllocator::~TAllocator()
{
    if (free < amount) {
        throw std::runtime_error("TAllocator: memory leak");
    }

    std::free(usedBlocks);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < root->N - 1; i++) {
        std::free(root->sons[i].data);
    }
    std::free(root->sons);
}
```

Я переделал под двоичное дерево:

```
TALLOCATOR.H
#ifndef TALLOCATOR_H
#define TALLOCATOR_H

#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdexcept>

struct TBTree {
    TBTree* left;
    TBTree* right;
    void* data;
};

class TAllocator
{
private:
    TBTree* root;
public:
    TAllocator();
    void* allocate();
    void deallocate(void*);
    ~TAllocator();
};

#endif
```

А вот как TALLOCATOR.CPP написать - хз.
Можете помочь?

Comment: Образец - Nдерево